# How to get bitcoin bip32 public key from private key?

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, public-key, bip

I need to know how to get the corresponding public key of a private key in hd-wallets, I don't need the derived ones but the public key who is related to the private I got. If there is an algorithm using python it will be very helpful but also the formula will be good as well.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know how to get the corresponding public key of a private key in hd-wallets, I don't need the derived ones but the public key who is related to the private I got.

A private key derived using the BIP32 hierarchical derivation is similar to any other one and the corresponding public key is obtained by "multiplying" your private by `G`, as for any other private key.

You want to use a specific crypto library for this operation, and I believe [`coincurve`](https://github.com/ofek/coincurve) to be a good maintained Python binding to [`libsecp`](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1).

You can also use [`python-bip32`](https://github.com/darosior/python-bip32) to simplify your use of BIP32 derived keys (relies on coincurve under the hood).